# Windows to Android - Hotspot doesn't work properly

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, mobile-hotspot

I have a laptop A running Windows 10, and a phone B running android.

I have ethernet connected to A, which runs properly with high speeds.

I turn on hotspot on A and turn on wifi on B, and connect. More often than not, I won't be able to browse internet on B in this configuration. This is while internet on A runs smoothly; and mobile data or any other wifi connection on B runs smoothly.

Note that this is quite random: sometimes the A-B connection runs nicely; but the case that it won't is more often.

How to troubleshoot this, and what are the possible causes?

Comment: How does the WiFi hotspot identify itself? If the SSID changes each time the PC is used, is there a commonality in names where connection succeeds, or it fails? See https://nordvpn.com/blog/what-is-ssid/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The network name is constant always.